# Python opening file name with +

Tags: python, file-io, naming-conventions

I am trying to write a file name in this format sam_192.168.1.5_error.txt but it's having problem when i add name.

```
name=str(s_name[1])
f = open(name+'_'+HOST+'_error.txt','a')
```

Comment: You need to explain what problem exactly "it's having", i.e. what happens and what do you want to happen.

Comment: I'm guessing you want to use `str(HOST)` instead of just `HOST`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to put all of the variables in `str()` form to open a file of their name:

```
filename = name+"_"+host+"_"+"error.txt"
f = open(str(filename),"a")
```

is the easiest way to do it.

Comment: So i did that and now it's just sitting at the line where i do the f=open(str(filename),'a').  I did print filename before that and format is correct, but why is it just paused?

Comment: What should your program do now? Is there more code to come? Did you try to append data to the file? Did you close the file?

Comment: It shouldn't have - try re-running it. What version of Python are you using? Does it do anything else afterwards? Do you get an error?

Comment: well if i just do the host in the file name the code executes and appends the error that is is collecting from reading a buffer.  The other part of the code works fine when i don't have the name added in the file name.

Comment: I'm assuming name is a string type, so I can't see a problem. You could always try `filename = "_"+host+"_"+"error.txt"
f = open(name+str(filename),"a")` (on two seperate lines) but I can't really help you there. I'll have a think about it... try and give us more information if you can.

Comment: name is type str and I tried your suggestion and it still doesn't work.  If I can print the filename with the correct name why couldn't I create a file is what's confusing to me.

Comment: figured it out.  I had an extra space before the names of the name variable and as soon as i got rid of that, it worked.